# "Since they partnered up they have made a lot of money"

Tags: past-tense, perfect-constructions

> Since they partnered up they have made a lot of money.

Or should it be

> Since they had partnered up they have made a lot of money.

because first they partnered up and only then they have made a lot of money

Comment: both your examples are correct.

Answer (score -1):

> **Since they partnered up, they have made a lot of money**.
>
> **Since they had partenered up, they have made a lot of money.**

I think both the sentences arecorrect.Since they partenered up refers to a point of time in the past though it is in the past tense because of the conjunction since.You can use past perfect because some times past perfect and simple past are interchangeable